# Unix Date Current Day -(Minus) Day (Yesterday Date)

Tags: shell, date, unix, terminal, operating-system

I'm trying to get the previous day (yesterday) date. I'm using that command in my script (`date +%Y%m%d -d "yesterday"`), but I'm getting the current day date. I'm using Unix, not Linux.

Can you guys suggest a solution to how I can get yesterday's date on the Unix terminal?

Comment: What version of Unix are you using? On my Macintosh, `date -v -1d +%Y%m%d` works just fine, but the `-d` flag is used to set daylight saving, so I guess you're working with something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Perl available (and your date doesn't have nice features like yesterday), you can use:

```
> date
Thu Aug 18 19:29:49 XYZ 2010

> dt=$(perl -e 'use POSIX;print strftime "%d/%m/%Y%",localtime time-86400;')

> echo $dt
17/08/2010
```

Comment: Hi Magdoud!
Thanks for your suggestion.
But I'm using the plain script without Perl. Can you please suggest the solution only for the Unix terminal?